# add db column to textbox and save it in db (total)

Tags: c#

I want to add the value in a textbox to a column in db called Quantity by using Update, so every time i click save will collection that in db (Quantity)
I'm sorry my English not good

note: db=invoice , Table=Product
Edit: solve it , i hope this code will be usefull for ppl

```
         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=NAWAF;Initial Catalog=invoice;Integrated Security=True");

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [invoice].[dbo].[invoice]
            ([Invoice_Number]
            ,[Inventory_ID]
            ,[Received_Date]
            ,[Supplier_Code]
            ,[Supplier_Name]
            ,[Product_Code]
            ,[Product_name]
            ,[Serial_Number]
            ,[MGF_Date]
            ,[Product_unit]
            ,[ReceivedQ])
       VALUES     
            ('" + textBox1.Text + "' ,'" + comboBox1.Text + "' , '" + textBox3.Text + "' , '" + comboBox2.Text + "' , '" + comboBox3.Text + "' , '" + comboBox4.Text + "' , '" + comboBox5.Text + "' , '" + textBox2.Text + "' , '" + textBox4.Text + "' , '" + comboBox6.Text + "' , '" + textBox6.Text + "')", con);

               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

               con.Close();
               con.Open();
               SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Invoice_Number,Received_Date,Supplier_Code,Supplier_Name,Product_Code,Product_name,Serial_Number,MGF_Date,ReceivedQ from invoice where   Invoice_Number like '" + textBox1.Text + "'", con);
               DataTable dt = new DataTable();
               sda.Fill(dt);
               dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
              SqlCommand ccm= new SqlCommand("UPDATE product SET quantity += '" + textBox6.Text + "' FROM product WHERE Product_name like '" + comboBox5.Text + "'", con);
               ccm.ExecuteNonQuery();
               textBox3.Text = "";
               textBox2.Text = "";
               textBox4.Text = "";
               comboBox4.Text = "";
               comboBox5.Text = "";
               comboBox6.Text = "";
               textBox6.Text = "";
               con.Close();



    }
```

Comment: 1st, your query open to sql injection, try to use `paremeter.addwithvalue`, google for it, 2nd, what is the issue?

Comment: Please provide a concise example, not copy paste the whole code. This code can not be compiled. What is "con", I assume its connection. We are here to help. Please provide a code which can compile , concise. Do not put everything but give a sample. A tip! Please write the member names, properties such that it explains itself. For example use "sqlCommand" instead of "cmd"

Comment: Do you want to map the Table's column to a TextBox? If that so, you can either use `Tag` property of Textbox for such unless `Bind` it. I am guessing that you want to build your `INSERT` sql from such way.

Comment: i want to update the data in sql server , insert work perfectly, idont know how to update the data in other table when i insert data in invoice table

Comment: @AbhishekKumar im new and try to get help im so sorry for disturb

Comment: i solve it and update the code @AbhishekKumar

Answer (score 0):

Actually i do not understand in which query you have problem Insert or Update ?
you can try insert like this:

```
string query="INSERT INTO [invoice].[dbo].[invoice]([Invoice_Number],[Inventory_ID],[Received_Date],[Supplier_Code],[Supplier_Name],[Product_Code],[Product_name],[Serial_Number],[MGF_Date],[Product_unit],[ReceivedQ])           VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "' , '" + comboBox1.Text + "' , '" + textBox3.Text + "' , '" + comboBox2.Text + "' , '" + comboBox3.Text + "' , '" + comboBox4.Text + "' , '" + comboBox5.Text + "' , '" + textBox2.Text + "' , '" + textBox4.Text + "' , '" + comboBox6.Text + "' , '" + textBox6.Text + "')"

=new SqlCommand(query, con);

and update query Like this: 
new SqlCommand("UPDATE p SET quantity = '" + textBox6.Text + "' FROM PRODUCT p WHERE Product_name like '" + comboBox5.Text + "'")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
SqlCommand ccm= new SqlCommand("UPDATE product SET quantity = '" + textBox6.Text + "' FROM product WHERE Product_name like '" + comboBox5.Text + "'", con)
ccm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The problem is  `ExecuteNonQuery();` I should put it after every sqlcommand to work

I was thinking i shouldnt use it